# Build size understanding when importing dependencies

Tags: javascript, node.js, lodash

I was under this impression that when i user deconstruction to import only the functions i want would result in smaller build size. but after installing import size extension i got this numbers.
I don't know if this is specific to Lodash or is in general better to import by accessing sub directories of functions.

I wanted to make sure this is in general the way that build process works.

[image]